# How could Norby transport safely with Marcel?

Tags: time-travel, robots

In the Janet Asimov novel; "[Norby and the Queen's Necklace](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/116320.Norby_and_the_Queen_s_Necklace)", Norby and his owner are taken back to the time of the French Revolution and end up escaping the Bastille. They meet Marcel and then violate all sorts of physical laws by taking him with them to various points in time in order to discover the origin of the necklace.

We know that there were laws put in place (similar to Star Trek's "Temporal Prime Directive") but these were blatantly disobeyed. How was there not some sort of judicial system applied to this case that would punish the two for their violations of the law?

Comment: Time travelling robots. To up vote, or not to upvote?

Answer (score 1):

A casual glance at the earlier [Norby novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norby) suggests that there is absolutely no restriction on time travel, nor does there seem to be any judicial or extra-judicial authority in charge of policing the use of time travel.

The titular character travels to various time periods, often by accident but also deliberately. He uses time travel to circumvent locks and barriers (by travelling to a time when they didn't exist) as well as "jumping" to interesting moments in history, again seemingly with no consequence.

He seems to have some difficulty in travelling to points in time where he exists elsewhere but this seems an inconsistent "rule" that he ends up breaking on a fairly regular basis, thus allowing him to corrupt his own timeline.

In short, the books are a veritable "who's who" of temporal paradoxes. I counted at least two [bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_paradox) incidents, a [multiple universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_paradox#Multiple_universes_hypothesis) paradox and at least one ["butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_paradox#Timeline_corruption_hypothesis)" that magically resolves itself despite there being no logical solution.